# Create a csv file from gspread skipping some rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm creating a csv file to iterate it and send emails using Python.
Code works for me, but I think I'm doing too much coding just to get data from Google SpreadSheet, skip some rows, and iterate it.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from settings_djg import SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASS  # Email settings file
from datetime import date, datetime
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from email.message import EmailMessage
from itertools import islice

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("Hosting_Domains").sheet1
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_values() 

new_list = pd.DataFrame(list_of_hashes)

# Here I'm using .iloc to skip some rows
new_list.iloc[[0,2,3,4,5,6,7,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]].to_csv('my_csv.csv', index=False, header=False) 

msg = EmailMessage()
now = date.today()

# Here starts iteration
with open('my_csv.csv') as csv_file:   
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:
```

Data from Google SpreadSheet is like this:

```
X,DOMAIN,EXPIRE,OWNER,REGISTRANT,HOSTING
 ,,,CUSTOMERS,,,
B,company.com,2021-02-13,Customer,SITEGROUND,SITEGROUND
D,companyb.com,2021-05-17,Customer,GODDADY,GODDADY
E,companyc.com,2021-09-19,Customer,GODDADY,GODDADY
D,companye.com,2021-01-23,Customer,GODDADY,GODDADY
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is your current issue? 2. What is your expected result?

Comment: I was expecting: Going from my Google SpreadSheet to my csv file more easily without the "list of lists", and without using .iloc to skip some rows from the original file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your goal. I apologize for this. For example, when your sample value of `Data from Google SpreadSheet is like this:` is used, can I ask you about the result you expect?

Comment: Sorry, from my SpreadSheet, right now, to skip row[1] I'm using .iloc. My Q: Is there any easier way of doing it? Or using ".iloc" is a good option? Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your goal is to retrieve the values from Google Spreadsheet as CSV data by selecting rows using gspread with python. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly, 100% right!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Works great! Now looks better without iloc. Thanks for your patience and your time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from Google Spreadsheet as CSV data by selecting rows using gspread with python.

  - In this case, you don't want to use `iloc` and save it as a file.
- As a sample, you want to retrieve the rows from `[0,2,3,4,5,6,7,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]` of a sheet.

  - In this case, `0` is included. So I thought that `0` is the 1st row.

#### Modification point:

- When `[0,2,3,4,5,6,7,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]` is the index of array of `list_of_hashes`, I think that the required rows can be retrieved using `[0,2,3,4,5,6,7,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]`.

When this point is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_values()
values = [list_of_hashes[e] for e in [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
```

- `values` is the array retrieved the required rows.
- `df` is the dataframe converted from `values`.